# Customization of total order and additional infos

Tags: cart, template, totals

When want to have the following style of totals on `checkout/cart`:

> 1. Discount
> 2. Subtotal
> 3. Shipping fee OR Info Text: "excl. shipping"
> 4. Additional text: "free shipping from 30EUR" (display always)
> 5. Grand total
> 6. incl. Tax

Problems

> 1. Even if we set "**Checkout Totals Sort Order**" in the backend correctly, the grand total is always displayed at the end
> 2. How to put any additional info blocks between the totals?
> 3. How to display an info text, if one total is **not present** (shipping)

Answer (score 18):

***partial answer***

### 1. Order in Backend does not fully affect rendering

- The totals are rendered by an "area".
- The grand total is in the area "footer". See `template\checkout\cart\totals.phtml`.
- Passing `-1` to `renderTotals()` renders all areas.

So you have to remove `$this->renderTotals('footer');` and change
`$this->renderTotals();` to `$this->renderTotals(-1);`

Example (after copying `totals.phtml` to your own theme):

```
<table id="shopping-cart-totals-table">
    <col />
    <col width="1" />
    <tbody>
        <?php echo $this->renderTotals(-1); ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

After this change, the order configured in the back-end works as expected.