# Changing order of shopping cart totals is not working after changed the sequence from admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, sequence

I appreciate your solution for resolving my problem.

I have changed the cart totals sequence from my admin panel but it is not reflecting on the front end.
Steps for changing a sequence from admin panel: `System->Configuration->Sales->Checkout Total Sort Order`
Please find below my environment details which I am using on my production environment.Please help me!

```
magento version 1.9
php version 5.6
server nginx
```

Comment: I think this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109/customization-of-total-order-and-additional-infos link should be helpful for you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for providing the guidance.
After implementing the above link solution my problem has been resolved.

So you have to remove $this->renderTotals('footer'); and change
$this->renderTotals(); to $this->renderTotals(-1);

Example (after copying totals.phtml to your own theme):

`<table id="shopping-cart-totals-table">
    <col />
    <col width="1" />
    <tbody>
        <?php echo $this->renderTotals(-1); ?>
    </tbody>
</table>`